# Showing latest blog post at homepage using Jekyll

Tags: blogs, jekyll

I'm trying to show the latest blog post on the homepage using Jekyll. All the posts + paginator functionality works fine on `localhost:4000/blog/`, but I'd like to repeat this on the homepage.  The only other answer to this I've seen is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nimbupani/1421828), which I can't get my head round.

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem with the snippet you copied?

It works as follows: in `index.html`, it retrieves the first blog post (`site.posts.first`) and store it in the `post` variable, while its content is stored in `content`. After all that, it calls (`include`) the `post_detail.html` partial, which uses the same context as before.

So, in the end, it uses the first post (`post` variable) and its content (`content` variable) in the `post_detail.html` partial.

Hope that helps!